# Django Rest Framework - Using nested serializers or `depth=5`, desire flat heirarchy

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-rest-framework

I have a lot of nested foreign keys, they are currently being represented in JSON as so:

```
"test": {
    "b": {
        "c": {
            "d": {
                "e": {
                    "E": "echo"
                },
                "D": "delta"
            },
            "C": "charlie"
        },
        "B": "beta"
    },
    "A": "alpha"
}
```

I'd like it to be in this format:

```
"test": {
    "A": "alpha",
    "B": "beta",
    "C": "charlie",
    "D": "delta",
    "E": "echo"
}
```

How can this be accomplished in DRF?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to recurse the dictionary.

For example:

```
def flat(data):
    ret = {}
    for key, value in data.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            ret.update(flat(value))
        else:
            ret[key] = value
    return ret
```

Usage:

```
>>> data = {
...     "test": {
...         "b": {
...             "c": {
...                 "d": {
...                     "e": {
...                         "E": "echo"
...                     },
...                     "D": "delta"
...                 },
...                 "C": "charlie"
...             },
...             "B": "beta"
...         },
...         "A": "alpha"
...     }
... }
>>>
>>> {'test': flat(data['test'])}
{'test': {'A': 'alpha', 'C': 'charlie', 'B': 'beta', 'E': 'echo', 'D': 'delta'}}
```

Comment: Where would I put the code so that the JSON being sent has the recursion applied to it?